# Why so many custom data types in C?

Tags: c, variables, custom-data-type

Why are there so many custom data types like socklen_t, ssize_t, size_t, uint16_t? I don't understand the real need for them. To me, they’re just a bunch of new variable names to be learned.

Comment: Many types show *intent*, which is important to make code easy to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: There are no custom data types in C. `typedef` does not create a new data type, but an alias. And a type is not a variable.

Comment: Note that socklen_t and ssize_t are not standard C, they are defined by non-standard libraries.

Comment: If you find the names in C too many" already, you should never look at the language and standard libraries of Python, C++ or most other languages. Instead of learning every name, it's better to understand the idea and (if any) naming convention. Expecially for fixed-/least-/… width names it's very easy.

Comment: socklen_t and ssize_t are defined in the [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standard. It is different to the C standard, but its *System Interfaces* section describes features and facilities provided by a POSIX-compatible standard C library. This is the standard that defines sockets, signals, directory tree scanning, and so on. This means that OP needs to add the [tag:posix] tag, to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

Intent and portability.

For example, let's say I have a variable `unsinged n`. An unsigned integer can represent many things, so it's intent is not clear. But when I write `size_t n`, it is clear that `n` represents size of something. When I write `socklen_t n` it is clear that `n` represents the length of something related to socket.

Second reason is portability. For example, `socklen_t` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits. Now if we just write `unsigned n` then size of `n` may be less than 32 bits. `size_t` can hold the size of any object, but the actual value is implementation defined. When we use plain integer it may happen that `sizeof(int)` can't hold the size of largest object that is theoretically possible. But using `size_t` doesn't have such portability issue.

`uint16_t` clearly says that it is unsigned integer of 16 bits which is both clear and portable than using `unsigned int` or `unsigned short`.

Comment: I don't understand "Now if we just write unsigned n then size of n may be less than 32 bits."

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, It provides **more readability**.

Secondly, while programming for embedded systems or cross platform or when portability is important, it is necessary of be explicit about the size of the data type that you are using - using these **specific data types avoids confusion and guaranteed to be having the defined data width.**